# Ubuntu Software redirecting to Snap Store

Tags: snap, 22.10

I've been going through an interesting situation after upgrading to version 22.10 where Ubuntu Software, after opened by the dock, redirects to the Snap Store.

[image]

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?

Comment: The same is happening in 22.04.1. Normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It seems that the old **Ubuntu Software** store has been discontinued and merged into the **Snap Store**. However, after selecting a specific software in the new Snap Store, you can go to the top right menu list and see if there is a ".deb" version provided by Ubuntu and install that. The "new" Snap Store is a bit buggy though.

If you really want to install the "old" GNOME **Software** tool, you can try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```